# Class level variable?

Tags: c#

I get this error `object reference is required on clindID in the submethod` 
Why can't I access the string clientID in the sub class Methods? I'd like to use it in multiple methods.

```
class Remote
{
    public string clientID
    {
       set{} get { return this.clientID; }
    }

    public bool validClientId()
    {
        clientID="32";
        return true;
    }
// closing bracket?
```

Or would it be better to use

```
string clientID="";
```

which doesn't work either

Comment: ...and what errors do you get?

Comment: what do you mean by not works can you show proper class code it is not looking complete code

Comment: object reference is required on clindID in the submethod

Comment: @mountaindweller you're probably trying to access it as if it were a static variable. Let me guess, your code has `Remote.clientID`?

Comment: Have you posted the proper failing code? The object reference error points to something being `static`...

Comment: Did you try `remote.validClientId();` and was that the failing code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you didn't reference the variable using an object reference in your `validClientId()` method (as described by T McKeown's answer), your code is looking within the scope of the `validClientId()` method itself to find that variable. It can't find it because the variable hasn't been declared within that scope. Try including the object reference as described by T McKeown to force the compiler to look within the `this` object for that variable.

Also, your class brackets aren't closed. This might just be a problem with your example code, but you need a closing curly brace `}`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a setter implemented.

```
    public string clientID
    {
        get { return this.patientID; }
        set { this.patientID  = value;  }
    }
```

Comment: Not implementing the setter would make the code compile, but not work, rather than not compiling, as the is stating is the case.

Comment: why's that?  What am i missing?

Comment: The OP has a setter, it's implementation is just blank.  That means he can call the setter just fine, it just won't actually set anything.  The OP is stating he's getting a compiler error.  This problem with his code wouldn't cause that, so while this is clearly wrong, it won't fix the problem he's asking about.

Comment: still the same issue, what if I just removed that property and added string patientid=""; to the top of the class above the methods, why isn't that working either?

Comment: i think you need to show more code and where the error is occuring.

Comment: you say sub method...  are you showing the base or the sub?  also the class you posted is private, so I am cleary confused.

Comment: ok it's public static, once i remove static it works, but i'd like to keep the method static is that possible?

Comment: please update your example, i cannot figure out from your words what the issue is.